# How did traditional acharyas and scholars of the Vedas interpret Indra being an important god in the Vedas?

Tags: vedas

How did acharyas and scholars of the Vedas before the 19th century interpret Indra being such an important god in the Vedas?

Comment: What is definition of important? Lord Vishnus is mentioned more times than Indra in Vedas. Besides Puranas and Itihasas also have Indra as prominent

Comment: In the four Vedas Indra has far more mention than Vishnu does. Considering that Indra is below Vishnu in the Puranas, what did the acharyas and scholars who studied the Vedas think of Indra being so frequently mentioned as compared to Vishnu?

Comment: Ok. So let's ignore the other names of Vishnu and figure out. From Taittriya Aranyaka, CHP 8.                                             From the fear of Him Vatah (the wind) blows, from fear of Him the sun rises. From fear of Him the five divinities such as Agni (fire), Indra, and Mrityu (death) work.

Comment: the vedas are thousands of years old. The gods of the vedas were important during rig veda era, especially prior to the rise of the Uttara Mimamsa era of Vyasa - modern Vedanta, which includes all the dualistic (Madhva), qualified monistic (Ramanuja), and monistic (Shankaracharya) systems.

Comment: No need of interpretation. Indra is openly addressed as the King of the Gods and mightiest protector.